# Extending Angular 4 universal renderer

Tags: angular, renderer

I hope someone can help with the logic on this one.
I would like to modify the way angular universal injects the style for each component. 
Does anyone know how to extend the renderer an get the stylesheet from other place by doing an api request. I would just need an example on the renderer example and the api request I think I may figure out myself.

I am looking at this old one.
    https://github.com/ralfstx/angular2-renderer-example/blob/master/src/custom-renderer.ts

```
import {
    Injectable,
    Renderer,
    RootRenderer,
    RenderComponentType
} from '@angular/core';

export class Element {
    constructor(private nodeName: string, private parent?: Element) {

    }
    toString() {
        return '<' + this.nodeName + '>';
    }
};

@Injectable()
export class CustomRootRenderer extends RootRenderer {
    private _registeredComponents: Map<string, CustomRenderer> = new Map<string, CustomRenderer>();

    renderComponent(componentProto: RenderComponentType): Renderer {
        var renderer = this._registeredComponents.get(componentProto.id);
        if (!renderer) {
            renderer = new CustomRenderer(this);
            this._registeredComponents.set(componentProto.id, renderer);
        }
        return renderer;
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomRenderer extends Renderer {

    constructor(private _rootRenderer: CustomRootRenderer) {
        super();
        console.log('CustomRenderer created');
    }

    renderComponent(componentType: RenderComponentType): Renderer {
        return this._rootRenderer.renderComponent(componentType);
    }

    selectRootElement(selector: string): Element {
        console.log('selectRootElement', selector);
        return new Element('Root');
    }

    createElement(parentElement: Element, name: string): Element {
        console.log('createElement', 'parent: ' + parentElement, 'name: ' + name);
        return new Element(name, parentElement);
    }

    createViewRoot(hostElement: Element): Element {
        console.log('createViewRoot', 'host: ' + hostElement);
        return hostElement;
    }

    createTemplateAnchor(parentElement: Element): Element {
        console.log('createTemplateAnchor', 'parent: ' + parentElement);
        return new Element('?');
    }

    createText(parentElement: Element, value: string): Element {
        console.log('createText', 'parent: ' + parentElement, 'value: ' + value);
        return new Element('text');
    }

    projectNodes(parentElement: Element, nodes: Element[]) {
        console.log('projectNodes', 'parent: ' + parentElement, 'nodes: ' + nodes.map(node => node.toString()));
    }

    attachViewAfter(node: Element, viewRootNodes: Element[]) {
        console.log('attachViewAfter', 'node: ' + node, 'viewRootNodes: ' + viewRootNodes.map(node => node.toString()));
    }

    detachView(viewRootNodes: Element[]) {
        console.log('detachView', 'viewRootNodes: ' + viewRootNodes.map(node => node.toString()));
    }

    destroyView(hostElement: Element, viewAllNodes: Element[]) {
        console.log('destroyView', 'host: ' + hostElement, 'viewAllNodes: ' + viewAllNodes.map(node => node.toString()));
    }

    setElementProperty(renderElement: Element, propertyName: string, propertyValue: any): void {
        console.log('setElementProperty', 'element: ' + renderElement, 'name: ' + propertyName, 'value: ' + propertyValue);
    }

    setElementAttribute(renderElement: Element, attributeName: string, attributeValue: string): void {
        console.log('setElementAttribute', 'element: ' + renderElement, 'name: ' + attributeName, 'value: ' + attributeValue);
        return this.setElementProperty(renderElement, attributeName, attributeValue);
    }

    listen(renderElement: Element, eventName: string, callback: Function): Function {
        console.log('listen', 'element: ' + renderElement, 'eventName: ' + eventName);
        return function () { };
    }

    listenGlobal(target: string, eventName: string, callback: Function): Function {
        console.log('listen', 'target: ' + target, 'eventName: ' + eventName);
        return function () { };
    }

    // Used only in debug mode to serialize property changes to comment nodes,
    // such as <template> placeholders.
    setBindingDebugInfo(renderElement: Element, propertyName: string, propertyValue: string): void {
        console.log('setBindingDebugInfo', 'element: ' + renderElement, 'name: ' + propertyName, 'value: ' + propertyValue);
    }

    setElementClass(renderElement: Element, className: string, isAdd: boolean): void {
        console.log('setElementClass', 'className' + className, 'isAdd: ' + isAdd);
    }

    setElementStyle(renderElement: Element, styleName: string, styleValue: string): void {
        console.log('setElementStyle', 'name: ' + styleName, 'value: ' + styleValue);
    }

    invokeElementMethod(renderElement: Element, methodName: string, args: Array<any>) {
        console.log('invokeElementMethod', 'name: ' + methodName, 'args: ' + args);
    }

    setText(renderNode: Element, text: string): void {
        console.log('setText', 'node: ' + renderNode, 'text: ' + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can try to set View Encapsulation to None and append style to native body component after service call?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the issue for [Dynamically import a stylesheet depending on the environment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4685). So I think you can try to load dynamic style by:

- Add dynamic component as the guide at [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).
- Or apply styles via document object as:

  ```
  export class AppComponent
  {
     title = 'Dynamic load theme';
     constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

     lightTheme() {
        this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'light-theme.css');
     }

     darkTheme() {
        this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'dark-theme.css');
     }

  }
  ```

Here is a simple example on [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/TCyuJqCuSfs35TrGPW7k/).

Hope this help!